# Lower Bottom of Beamer Slide

Tags: beamer, textheight

I'm trying to put a large space in my Beamer slide. After some initial text I used a `\vfill` and then the text that's suppose to be at the bottom. But the bottom is very high. I've tried various `\textheight` type commands with no luck. I don't want to use `\vspace` with a specific measurement because the size of the top and bottom text changes on each slide (and sometimes I have titles/headings).

How do I lower the bottom of the text?

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeboxes}

\begin{document}

\frame{p \vfill

bottom}

\end{document}
```

The slide looks like this:
[image: Bottom of beamer slide should be lower]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `\vspace{-\fill}` after `bottom`.
This neutralizes the `\vfill` added to the end of every frame because of the `[t]` option.

This also explains why `bottom` appears centered within your frame: it is pushed down by your `\vfill` and pushed up by the `\vfill` added at the end.

[image]

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeboxes}
\begin{document}

\frame{p \vfill

bottom\vspace{-\fill}}

\end{document}
```